# Is there a way to add linecharts to a GlanceAppWidget?

Tags: glance-appwidget, glance

Pretty much the title, im trying to make a widget that contains some data and linecharts, i know this glance stuff is pretty new, so im not sure if its possible to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Glance is limited by the RemoteViews capabilities, thus you cannot create custom views. Instead you would need to render a bitmap with your linechart and use it in an `Image` composable.

I believe some graph libraries out there allow to export a chart to a drawable/bitmap